# How can I initialize an Object in one line?

Tags: c#, .net

I have to declare a list for my unit tests :

```
public void DataCleanTest1()
{
    List<MesureSerialized> data = new List<MesureSerialized>
    {
        { new MesureSerialized() },
        { new MesureSerialized() }
    };
}
```

I would like to initialize my objects and fill them in a line without having to manually set every field of the object.

I don't know the term used for this action so my researches were unsuccessfull.

Comment: What prevents you from doing it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx

Comment: You aren't doing anything "dynamically". These are plain old construction expressions. Just like `new List<>`. If you found the syntax for the collection initializer, the object initializer is in the same or previous documentation page or article

Comment: Fill with what?

Comment: @core114 the OP isn't asking about a problem with the code. It looks like a request for a tutorial or a link to the docs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's it, thanks, It looks like I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @core114 I did not edit the question.

Comment: Not sure why this question was so heavily down-voted. Looks like a classic SE circle-jerk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the so called [Object Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```
public void DataCleanTest1()
{
    List<MesureSerialized> data = new List<MesureSerialized>
    {
        {
            new MesureSerialized
            {
                Prop1 = "value",
                Prop2 = 42
            }
        },
        { new MesureSerialized() }
    };
}
```

Please also note that you don't need the curly braces around the objects in the list.

This is equally valid:

```
public void DataCleanTest1()
{
    List<MesureSerialized> data = new List<MesureSerialized>
    {
        new MesureSerialized
        {
            Prop1 = "value",
            Prop2 = 42
        },
        new MesureSerialized()
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's it :D

Answer (score 6):

Maybe i don't understand the question, you want to do :

```
public void DataCleanTest1()
{
    List<MesureSerialized> data = new List<MesureSerialized>
    {
        new MesureSerialized { myProperty = "value", otherPrperty = "value" },
        new MesureSerialized { myProperty = "value", otherPrperty = "value" }
    };
}
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses

Comment: You understood my question ! Thanks! I didn't know I could do that.